# I have VS C++ Express. Is there a way to create .DEF files?

Tags: c++, dll

I would be extremely appreciative if anybody can help me.
I am learning C++ and I have been trying figure this one out.

Basically, VS C++ Express does not come with the .DEF
template. What other way can I go about creating this file?

Is there a parameter I can set in VS so that the linker
can create this on the fly?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the syntax of a DF file defined in places like

- [Exporting from a DLL Using DEF Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(VS.80).aspx)
- [Module-Definition (.def) Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h(VS.80).aspx)

The bottom of the first link also mentions alternatives to DEF files (e.g. the `__declspec(dllexport)` directive).

If you don't have a template to create a DEF file, you can create the file manually using your text editor (using the syntax defined above).

After you've created it, then add it to your project's linker options (so that the linker uses it).

Answer (score 0):

Create it manually and name it yourcurrentproject.def and add export symbols in it.